# Number of Swaps of Binary Insertion Sort

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The number of comparisons in worst case binary insertions sort need is,

$$\sum_{k=2}^{n}(2\left\lceil \log(k)\right\rceil+1)$$

2 comparisons in the while loop and another in the for loop.

**Question:** I found that the number of swaps in worst case is the following, but is this true?
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(n-k)$$

as for each iteration of the outer for loop, we have to do swaps all over until the beginning of the list.

[image]

Comment: $$N=\sum _{k=1}^{n-1} (n-k)=\frac{1}{2} (n-1) n$$ means $N\sim 500000$ for $n=1000$. Looks a bit too much

Comment: @Raffaele. Thank you. Is my analysis right for swaps?